# android: how to open a file out of my app

Tags: android, eclipse, file

I'm developing an app, which should open a file after decoding.
So, I want to open a file (for example an image) picked in my app by a default application (if there are several apps for that kind of file then one of apps is to choose by user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For different file types you need to use different intents like the below

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
"Open image"), 1);
```

or you could use the following code to get the file type from the file and letthe android system figure out which app it can be opened with

```
File file = new File("EXAMPLE.JPG");


String mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(".JPG");
//You need to find the extension from the file using a split command
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mime);
startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Instead of splitting I used this:
    String ext = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file2open);  before of this: String mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext); The rest has worked properly.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. Thanks a lot again.